# How could I remove the color of the navigation sidebar?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to simplify my slides and remove the color of the navigation sidebar. How could I do that? This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{A long title}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{A section}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of beamer elements can be set with `\setbeamercolor`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{A long title}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{A section}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]